# Create per project path aliases by extending tsconfig.base.json

Tags: typescript, nrwl-nx

I am working on NX monorepo and currently I have two libs and a single app.

1. The two library path aliases are registered in `tsconfig.base.json` as follows:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@sca/config": ["libs/sca-config/src/index.ts"],
      "@sca/utils": ["libs/sca-utils/src/index.ts"]
    }
  }
}
```

2. In library `sca-config`, the `tsconfig.json` looks like:

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["libs/sca-config/src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

3. In library `sca-utils`, the `tsconfig.json` looks like:

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["libs/sca-utils/src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Now, considering that I haven't overriden the `baseUrl` in both the libraries, I must be able to use path alias `@sca/utils` in `sca-config`. Also while in both projects, I must be able to import the files from within the projects using `@/some/internal/project/file`.

This is not happening at the moment, it looks like the inherited paths are overridden completely instead of inheriting.

I tried to do this in `tsconfig.json` of `sca-config` and it worked, but it looks ugly. Also it seems, I have to do this for every library import:

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["libs/sca-config/src/*"],
      "@sca/utils": ["libs/sca-utils/src/index.ts"]
    }
  }
}
```

which confirms the fact that extending the `tsconfig.base.json` and then adding path to project level `tsconfig.json` overrides the `paths` property instead of merging it.

My question is, is there a nice way of doing it? Bacause it will get too much messy once the number of libraries and their dependence on each other grows. Not to mention, it will get repetitive to *(adding in both `tsconfig.base.json` and project level `tsconfig.json`)*

Comment: why would you want to use `@/*` in the libary. why not use relative path in the libaries?

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, this is a nice way of adding imports. I can also use (and I am using) relative imports, but relative imports add this `../../folder/something` type of imports. Isn't it better to write the imports like `@/folder/something`. You don't have to traverse the file tree to import a file, you just start directly from the source root.

Comment: i think you could always use absolut pathing. So `folder/something` should be the same to `../../folder/something`. Then u dont need the `@/*`

Comment: Unable to do so. Have tried this already